How to write an extremely efficient AND testable GUID generator
I want to test a class with unit tests to ensure that it will work correctly in all kinds of circumstances. The class should generate unique results regardless of where (physical machine, vm, container,...) the class is running. It should even generate unique results if run multiple times in the same environment in parallel.
The problem is. The class is static and it's using a DateTime.Now call. If I would make the class non-static and use the TimeProvider struct it would all be nice and testable but... before you start, here is the catch

The class will be called many thousands of times per second. The production machine holding the record at the moment with 151964235 calls per second over a time of 2 Minutes. Static was chosen to not stress the GC.
Every solution provided needs to be at least as fast as the current implementation. This includes the actual runtime of the solution time for object creation and the stress on the GC.
The Solutions needs to be portable and able to run on Windows, Linux and Mac alike.
Other Ideas to make it even faster are of course highly welcome.
The main concern is about DateTime.Now. I will think about UniqueId and Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId later.

namespace My.Utils;

using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
///     <see cref="SequentialGuid" /> generates instances of <see cref="Guid" /> that are in ascending order.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     It is both unique and ordered.
/// </remarks>
public static class SequentialGuid
{
    private const uint GuidVersion8 = 0x8000;
    private const uint GuidVersion7 = 0x7000;
    private const uint Variant = 0x80000000;
    private const uint VariantMask = 0xC0000000;
    private const uint SequenceRollover = 0x1000;
    private static readonly MapperAb EmptyMapperAb = new();
    private static readonly MapperCd BaseMapperCd;
    private static readonly uint C;
    private static long _lastMilliseconds;
    private static uint _sequence;
    private static SpinLock _spinLock;

    static SequentialGuid()
    {
        _spinLock = new SpinLock(false);
        int rnd = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(int.MaxValue);
        rnd ^= Environment.MachineName.GetHashCode();
        BaseMapperCd.C = (uint)rnd;
        BaseMapperCd.C &= ~VariantMask;
        BaseMapperCd.C |= Variant;
        BaseMapperCd.D = (uint)(Environment.ProcessId ^ rnd);
        C = (uint)rnd;
        C &= ~VariantMask;
        C |= Variant;
    }

    public static Guid CreateVersion7()
    {
        return CreateVersion7(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
    }

    public static Guid CreateVersion7(in DateTimeOffset timestamp)
    {
        var mapperAb = EmptyMapperAb;
        GetTicksAndSequence(timestamp, ref mapperAb);
        mapperAb.B |= GuidVersion7;

        var d = (uint)RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(int.MaxValue);
        Vector128<byte> vec = Vector128.Create(mapperAb.A, mapperAb.B, C, d).AsByte();
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Vector128<byte> result = Vector128.Shuffle(vec, Vector128.Create((byte)0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 11, 10, 9, 8, 15, 14, 13, 12));
            return Unsafe.As<Vector128<byte>, Guid>(ref result);
        }

        return Unsafe.As<Vector128<byte>, Guid>(ref vec);
    }

    public static Guid CreateVersion8()
    {
        return CreateVersion8(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
    }

    public static Guid CreateVersion8(in DateTimeOffset timestamp)
    {
        var mapperAb = EmptyMapperAb;
        GetTicksAndSequence(timestamp, ref mapperAb);
        mapperAb.B |= GuidVersion8;

        Vector128<byte> vec = Vector128.Create(mapperAb.A, mapperAb.B, BaseMapperCd.C, BaseMapperCd.D).AsByte();
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Vector128<byte> result = Vector128.Shuffle(vec, Vector128.Create((byte)0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 11, 10, 9, 8, 15, 14, 13, 12));
            return Unsafe.As<Vector128<byte>, Guid>(ref result);
        }

        return Unsafe.As<Vector128<byte>, Guid>(ref vec);
    }

    private static void GetTicksAndSequence(in DateTimeOffset timestamp, ref MapperAb mapperAb)
    {
        mapperAb.Ticks = timestamp.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(mapperAb.Ticks, nameof(timestamp));

        var lockTaken = false;
        _spinLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
        if (mapperAb.Ticks > _lastMilliseconds)
        {
            _sequence = 0;
            _lastMilliseconds = mapperAb.Ticks;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_sequence == SequenceRollover) // rollover will happen, so we increase ticks
            {
                _sequence = 0;
                ++_lastMilliseconds;
            }

            mapperAb.Ticks = _lastMilliseconds;
        }

        uint b = _sequence++;
        if (lockTaken) { _spinLock.Exit(); }

        mapperAb.Ticks <<= 16;
        mapperAb.B |= b;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct MapperAb
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public long Ticks;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public uint B;
        [FieldOffset(sizeof(uint))] public uint A;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct MapperCd
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public uint D;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort ProcessId;
        [FieldOffset(sizeof(ushort))] public byte ThreadId;
        [FieldOffset(sizeof(ushort) + sizeof(byte))] public byte TaskId;
        [FieldOffset(sizeof(uint))] public uint C;
    }
}

Update this are my current benchmark results.

This is the source code of the Benchmark
namespace Guid.Benchmarks;

using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNetVisualizer;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using Matching.Utils;

// ReSharper disable once ClassCanBeSealed.Global
[MaxColumn]
[MemoryDiagnoser(false)]
[MinColumn]
[RichHtmlExporter("Benchmark of UUID Creation",
                  ["Job"],
                  ["Mean", "Allocated"],
                  ["Mean", "Min", "Max", "Allocated"],
                  dividerMode: RenderTableDividerMode.SeparateTables,
                  htmlWrapMode: HtmlDocumentWrapMode.RichDataTables)]
[ShortRunJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net90)]
[UsedImplicitly]
public class BenchmarkSequentialGuidCreation
{
    [Benchmark]
    public Guid BenchmarUuidV4() => Guid.NewGuid(); // UUIDv4

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public Guid BenchmarkUuidV7() => Guid.CreateVersion7(); // UUIDv7

    [Benchmark]
    public Guid BenchmarkUuidV7Custom() => SequentialGuid.CreateVersion7(); // UUIDv7

    [Benchmark]
    public Guid BenchmarkUuidV8Custom() => SequentialGuid.CreateVersion8(); // UUIDv7
}

Update: I did have a look into the UUID v7 in .net9 that was mentioned by @Fildor. However, UUID v7 does pretty much the same I do but is significant slower than my implementation.
Update: I did have a look at the EF Core 8 implementation mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos. This implementation uses not a real time component, instead it uses the time when the object is initialized as a base for all other Ids created. This can be problematic in a scenario where processes that use this class will be stopped and started again. There is also nothing else in place to ensure uniqueness.
Update: I did update the code with my final implementation. This version is Testable in unit tests and follows the implementation of Guid.CreateVersion7. I also create a CreateVersion8 that may be predictable but also is twice as fast.

Did you consider UUID v7 (coming with dotnet 9, I think) or something like ULID ?

Is your question really about unit testing?

@Fildor UUID v7 is exactly what I need, I seem to have missed that. However I am stuck with .net8 at the moment. We can not hold deployment until .net9 is released. After it is released I will gladly switch to UUID v7.
But in fact that could be an angle to skip unit tests for this class and just use it as a placeholder till .net9 is released.

If you want to mock the time you can use System.TimeProvider. That won't help unit test this class though. A tick is pretty long. The real test will be running your code from multiple threads for a long time and checking for duplicates. You'll be surprised.

EF Core 8 has a sequential GUID generator. The source code is a lot simpler. Instead of locks it uses Interlocked.Increment to increment a counter.  The ticks are hard-coded (just like your code) but if you really think it's necessary, you can use System.TimeProvider. That won't help you test what happens if 10 threads try to generate GUIDs at once

@PanagiotisKanavos see the update in the post

You didn't notice that EF Core uses a modifed GUID for the initial bytes and then uses ticks just as  your own code does. Incrementing counters is done using Interlocked.Increment, a cheaper way than using locks. This algorithm is already tested millions of times and does produce unique primary key values, as any database errors would cause database errors. BTW what's the point of subtracting an offset from the ticks, when you don't really use them as a time?

In any case, I already explained what you need to do to ensure the code works. You can use System.TimeProvider instead of DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks so you can control the tick value. Unfortunately, using RandomNumberGenerator as a static prevents you from specifying a seed, so there's no way to control the random numbers. The real test will come when you use 10 or 20  threads or tasks to generate GUIDs and store them into a ConcurrentDictionary until you get a duplicate key exception

.NET 9 is open source anyway so you can inspect and copy .NET 9's CreateVersion7. Just like EF Core, it uses a GUID as starting point. Instead of static ticks it receives a DateTimeOffset parameter with a parameterless overload CreateVersion7() => CreateVersion7(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);, thus removing the need for mocking. The comments even discuss the use of RandomGenerator vs native GUID APIs on Unix and Windows

Are you sure, you can beat the performance of https://github.com/RobThree/NUlid ?

Look at CryptoRandom. It can generate GUIDs quickly.

@AlexanderPetrov thanks for the suggestion but.
CryptoRandom does not generate ordered guids.
CryptoRandom totally ignores RFC4112 and RFC9562
Given that, CryptoRandom is not the right choice for my usecase and due to the missing RFC compliant should not be a choice for any use case out there.

@Oliver Yes I can. Even Guid.CreateVersion7 is faster than Ulid with or without conversion to Guid it does not matter. (Ulid.NewUlid().ToGuid() -> 90.86ns, Ulid.NewUlid() -> 81.89 ns). Also Ulid ignores RFC4112 and RFC9562 so the usage as Guid is non existing. Even if I could use Ulid directly, there is still the lack of performance.

Sorry, referenced the wrong project. I meant this .Net library. It states, it is even faster then normal Guid. Just remembered this video from Nick.

Pass the ticks or even a DateTimeOffset as a parameter to NextGuid instead of using Datetime.UtcNow.Ticks internally. Create a parameterless overload for general use that uses Now as the default timestamp
public static Guid NewGuid()=>NewGuid(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

public static Guid NewGuid(DateTimeOffset timestamp)
{
...
}

That's what .NET 9's Guid.CreateVersion7 does. You could even copy that code for use in .NET 8 or .NET 6 (for the 2 months of support it has), but note that adding v7 support required changes to Guid.Unix.cs.
public static Guid CreateVersion7() => CreateVersion7(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);

The CreateVersion7(DateTimeOffset) implementation uses a v4 GUID whose 48 MSBs are replaced by the Unix timestamp in milliseconds, thus producing a v7 sequential UUID. The comments even discuss the use of native GUID functions vs RandomNumberGenerator (it's slower).
/// <summary>Creates a new <see cref="Guid" /> according to RFC 9562, following the Version 7 format.</summary>
/// <param name="timestamp">The date time offset used to determine the Unix Epoch timestamp.</param>
/// <returns>A new <see cref="Guid" /> according to RFC 9562, following the Version 7 format.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="timestamp" /> represents an offset prior to <see cref="DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch" />.</exception>
/// <remarks>
///     <para>This seeds the rand_a and rand_b sub-fields with random data.</para>
/// </remarks>
public static Guid CreateVersion7(DateTimeOffset timestamp)
{
    // NewGuid uses CoCreateGuid on Windows and Interop.GetCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes on Unix to get
    // cryptographically-secure random bytes. We could use Interop.BCrypt.BCryptGenRandom to generate the random
    // bytes on Windows, as is done in RandomNumberGenerator, but that's measurably slower than using CoCreateGuid.
    // And while CoCreateGuid only generates 122 bits of randomness, the other 6 bits being for the version / variant
    // fields, this method also needs those bits to be non-random, so we can just use NewGuid for efficiency.
    Guid result = NewGuid();

    // 2^48 is roughly 8925.5 years, which from the Unix Epoch means we won't
    // overflow until around July of 10,895. So there isn't any need to handle
    // it given that DateTimeOffset.MaxValue is December 31, 9999. However, we
    // can't represent timestamps prior to the Unix Epoch since UUIDv7 explicitly
    // stores a 48-bit unsigned value, so we do need to throw if one is passed in.

    long unix_ts_ms = timestamp.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(unix_ts_ms, nameof(timestamp));

    Unsafe.AsRef(in result._a) = (int)(unix_ts_ms >> 16);
    Unsafe.AsRef(in result._b) = (short)(unix_ts_ms);

    Unsafe.AsRef(in result._c) = (short)((result._c & ~VersionMask) | Version7Value);
    Unsafe.AsRef(in result._d) = (byte)((result._d & ~Variant10xxMask) | Variant10xxValue);

    return result;
}

The GuidTests.CreateVersion7 method uses this to ensure the values are the expected ones. It doesn't try to test for uniqueness, memory consumption.
    [Fact]
    public static void CreateVersion7()
    {
        DateTimeOffset timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        ReadOnlySpan<char> unix_ts_ms = timestamp.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString("x12", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Guid guid = Guid.CreateVersion7(timestamp);
        ReadOnlySpan<char> guidString = guid.ToString("", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Assert.Equal(7, guid.Version);
        Assert.True((guid.Variant == 0x8) || (guid.Variant == 0x9) || (guid.Variant == 0xA) || (guid.Variant == 0xB));

        Assert.Equal(unix_ts_ms.Slice(0, 8), guidString.Slice(0, 8));
        ...

The unit test just checks that the bytes are correct. To ensure your algorithm works though you need to ensure that two threads won't produce the same value on the same machine. Uniqueness just doesn't exist - UUIDs aren't unique, they just have such a small chance of collision they're treated as unique. Sequential UUIDs have a higher but still very small chance of collision.
One way you can test your algorithm is to create eg 10, 20 or more tasks/threads that generate UUIDs and add them to a ConcurrentDictionary. If the algorithm is prone to race conditions, you'll get a duplicate key exception after a while.
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Guid>();

Parallel.For(0, 1000000, new () { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 32 }, _ =>
{
    var guid = Guid.CreateVersion7();
    if (!dict.TryAdd(guid, guid))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Duplicate GUID!");
    }
});


Benchmarking
To test performance and allocation behavior, the defacto standard is Anderi Akinshin's BenckmarkDotNet. Instead of just running code multiple times and calculating an average, it runs tests long enough to gather statistically significant results. It will even warn if the results seem to vary too wildly. To account for warmup and cooldown effects, the tests will be run multiple times before it starts collecting measures.
This example benchmarks Guid.NewGuid() vs Guid.CreateVersion7() and EF8's SequentialGuidValueGenerator, collecting memory statistics as well :
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly);

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class GuidVsSequential
{

    SequentialGuidValueGenerator _gen;
    public GuidVsSequential()
    {
        _gen = new SequentialGuidValueGenerator();
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public Guid V4() => Guid.NewGuid();

    [Benchmark]
    public Guid Sequential() => Guid.CreateVersion7();

    [Benchmark]
    public Guid EF8() => _gen.Next();
}

The result summary is this :
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet v0.14.0, Windows 11 (10.0.22635.3936)
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK 9.0.100-rc.1.24452.12
  [Host]     : .NET 9.0.0 (9.0.24.43107), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
  DefaultJob : .NET 9.0.0 (9.0.24.43107), X64 RyuJIT AVX2




Method
Mean
Error
StdDev
Ratio
RatioSD
Allocated
Alloc Ratio




V4
67.73 ns
1.374 ns
2.987 ns
1.00
0.06
-
NA


Sequential
101.57 ns
2.030 ns
2.711 ns
1.50
0.08
-
NA


EF8
79.48 ns
1.619 ns
3.847 ns
1.18
0.08
-
NA



Interestingly, the EF8 code is a big faster than Guid.CreateVersion7 but doesn't produce valid UUID v7 values, as it doesn't convert to a Unix timestamp and doesn't set the version bytes.

I do get your point, and I am thinking of  using the version with the timestamp as parameters too. However I need to see the effect on performance first and at least my implementation is faster, not on the first call, but on every following call. In case of uniqueness I do not see a difference between my and the CreateVersion7 implementation. But I will adapt the existing unit tests just to make sure.

@IamanSwtrse that's the job of BenchmarkDotNet an OSS project created by Andrey Akinshin that ended up being the de-facto standard, used by the .NET team itself. It will repeat every benchmark method until it collects statistically valid results, take care of warmup and cooldown effects

@IamanSwtrse I added an example using BenchmarkDotNet

Thats what I am doing at the moment. However, since I do not trust the JIT compiler completely to not optimize unused return values away I added some benchmarks with a little bit of boilerplate  code and a loop running the Creation Methods int.MaxValue times. But thats maybe my paranoia. I will update my question and post the Benchmark and Report as soon as the benchmark is finished

That's why you need BenchmarkDotNet. It already takes care of all these concerns, including more serious ones like progressive optimization - the more the code runs, the more it gets optimized.

Sorry I was not clear enough. I do use BenchmarkDotNet for my benchmarks. I just do not trust it blindly :)

Why? If your concern was correct no benchmark would run as all would be eliminated. There wouldn't be different statistics in the 3 cases. If you don't trust the compiler, don't trust the runtime libraries, don't trust the profilers and benchmarks used by the runtime itself (and get updated by the people that created the JIT compiler)  ..................

I have added my benchmark to the question. Based on that maybe I should make some performance proposals. I also added the overloaded method that accepts a DateTimeOffset. Since this is not slowing down the speed at all I accept this as the valid answer.


Throw away this class and create a new class with a proper name: SequentialGuidGenerator. (A proper name reflects exactly what a class does, and not something different, let alone something entirely different, and oh-god-please-certainly-not something misleading.)

Make the class non-static. By having given the class a proper name, it should now be clear that this class is not going to be instantiated each time you want a GUID, it is only going to be instantiated once in a production environment, therefore there is no concern whatsoever about "object instantiation overhead", "stressing the GC", etc. The actual generation of a GUID will, of course, involve no instantiation, as before. The fact that the NewGuid() method will now accept an implicit this parameter might add a clock cycle or so to each invocation, but a) you probably have a clock cycle to spare anyway, and b) even if you do not have a clock cycle to spare, we will be reclaiming lots of clock cycles further down, keep reading.

Add a private readonly Int64 invariant field which is initialized from a constructor parameter.

Add a private Int64 counter field which always starts at 0, and gets incremented by 1 each time it is accessed, using InterlockedIncrement(), not a SpinLock.

Each time you want to issue a new GUID, form it by combining the invariant with the (incremented) counter, making sure that the invariant is the most significant part, and the counter is the least significant part. Refer to the documentation of Guid.CompareTo() to see how GUIDs are compared, and also, very importantly, how they must be constructed in order to be comparable.

On production, instantiate your generator with an invariant which is guaranteed to be different and increasing from run to run. This can simply come from System.DateTime.Now, or it can be negotiated by other means, since performance does not matter during the instantiation of the generator.

In the tests, instantiate your generator with a hard-coded invariant, so that the tests know what to expect.


The above construct guarantees unique, sequentially incrementing GUIDs with the following limits:
If you use System.DateTime.Now for the invariant you can keep restarting until the year 10000 AD; if you want more than that, you can negotiate invariants that increment by one on each restart, so you will be able to do about nine quintillion restarts. A quintillion is a one followed by 18 zeros, so this should last way past the year 10000 AD.
After a restart, you will be able to issue about nine quintillion GUIDs before another restart is needed.  This means that even if you could be generating a GUID once every 10 clock cycles, (you can't,) you would need a restart not more often than once every 30 years or so.
As for any problems that you might be experiencing while implementing the above, or any other concerns that you might still have, as indicated in the comments, (such as inability to get the class to work optimally unless the class is static, duplicate "guid time components" after a restart, the counter being "way before" the "time ticks", destroying "the order", "less calls of NewGuid() than Ticks", the "time order" not being "guaranteed", "time bases" problems, getting more than 1 Guid "out of the System" in 100ns, the counter being "faster than the time ticks", what your "local machine" is capable of and what "much more powerful servers" can do, etc.) these are all due to failure to follow the method outlined in my answer, which is in turn either due to failure to understand it, or due to failure to implement it.

Every time I tried this approach I run into the problem of generating duplicate guid time components when for some reason the process is stopped and started again. This happens when the counter you are proposing is way before the actual time ticks when this happens. This will destroy the order and therefore the main reason for this class. If a restart of the process who is using this class could be prevented this of course would be the fastes solution.
I will however stick to the SIMD Version using Vector128 since it is faster.

What do you mean by "the counter is way before the actual time ticks" ?  And what do you mean by "when this happens" ?

In any case, there should be no such problem: The timestamp guarantees uniqueness from process run to process run, and the counter guarantees uniqueness within a process run.

Also, by placing the "invariant" (timestamp or whatever else) in the most significant part of the GUID, order is also guaranteed.

I made an amendment to my answer which might help clarify things.

order is only guaranteed if you can guarantee that there are less calls of NewGuid() than Ticks since the initialization of the class. If at any time this is not the case and a restart happens at that time order is not guaranteed.

With an incrementing counter, you essentially have a "tick" on each invocation of NewGuid().  The counter is 64 bits long, and it begins at zero each time you restart your process.  Are you planning on issuing 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 new GUIDs between restarts?

No this is a time bases problem if manage to get more than 1 Guid out of the System in 100ns. The counter will be faster than the time ticks. This is what my local machine is capable of and if my local machine can do that the much more powerful server can do it too. But this does only apply if at your point 6 for example System.DateTime.Now is used as initialization so that would have to be handled differently.
However be it JIT optimization or some ither reason, solutions with non static classes never came close to the performance shown in my question now.
